# Merging many .rar files in one .rar file

Tags: windows-8.1, ntfs, compression, rar, file-archiver

I have about 200GB of rar part files (all .rar) that I would like to merge into 1 single .rar file. I'm trying to perform this in Windows. How would one go about merging many a rar file without decompressing all of them and recompressing those files into 1 .rar file?

Comment: **The NTFS file size limit is 16TB-256TB not 256GB** You would have to extract the archive then create a new archive that isn't spanned accross several files.

Comment: A quick google search shows [at least one solution](http://join-merge-combine-multiple-rar-files-in.software.informer.com/download/) for a specific OS.  Could you add for which OS you are willing to use. (Itf you run out of tags then remove the NTFS tag since it appears irrelevant - See Ramhounds comment).

Comment: Ramhounds comment does not help, I'm looking for a solution that will avoid that method as per my last statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue could be resolved. I found a tool which might fulfill your requirement.

You may download a Sobolsoft Tool to merge multiple RAR files into a single file without decompressing all. Here is an excerpt from the link i found this tool from.

Unlike some other RAR tools which allow you to nest a RAR file into another, or force you to decompress the RAR files before creating a new one with all the resulting files, this effective tool from Sobolsoft simply merges existing RAR files into a new, compressed RAR file, without decompressing anything, or nesting files, and thus making it easier for you to find a specific file within a RAR container. The new resulting file will contain all those files previously included in the original containers, and following the order in which their respective files were when the merging process started.

For more about this, you may follow the link http://join-merge-combine-multiple-rar-files-in.software.informer.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the "Convert Archives" feature of WinRAR.  It's in the tools menu or you can press Alt+Q.  Just add the first file to convert then in the conversion settings ensure that the split archive is not enabled.  Unfortunately, WinRAR does not combine the compressed files directly but must extract them.   Even so I'm hoping it is faster than the alternative.  I backed up a Linux partition and now need the files  for a restore but Linux does poor with RAR support so I'm going to convert many to Zip or 7Zip using p7Zip.   The archive has 240,000 files in just 6GB!

Off Topic but if you do want to convert them to Zip I found this but have not tested it yet. ezyzip.com/convert-rar-to-zip.html
"Unlike other online utilities, ezyZip DOES NOT have file size restrictions or require you to upload / download files to a server.  It runs locally as a browser app, making it much quicker than other similar online tools. Your privacy is protected as no file data leaves the browser. "